# Django and MySQL save multiple data

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to save multiple fields of data. I've also changed the database connection from the default sqlite3 to MySQL. And I don't know how to do this

Here's my views.py

```
def customerview(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.save():               
                return redirect('sales')
            else:
                return redirect('index')
        else:
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = CustomerForm
        return render(request, 'customer.html', {'form':form})

def salesview(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = SalesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.save(): 
                return redirect('index')
            else:
                return redirect('index')
        else:
            return redirect('index')
    else:
        form = SalesForm
        data = Customer.objects.latest('id')
        return render(request, 'sales.html', {'form':form, 'range':range(data.number_of_transactions)})
```

Here's my models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    number_of_transactions = models.IntegerField()

class Sales(models.Model):        
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_size = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

Here's my brands.html

```
<form class="form" role="form" action="" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    {% for i in range %}
        <div class="col">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="">
                    {{ form.product_type | add_class:'form-control' }}
                        <label for="regular2">Product Type</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="">
                    {{ form.product_code | add_class:'form-control' }}
                       <label for="regular2">Product Code</label>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     {% endfor %}
     <div class="col-md-12">
     <hr>
         <div class="card-actionbar-row">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-flat btn-primary ink-reaction" value="SUBMIT">
         </div>
     </div>
 </form>
```

The idea is to get the customer details and number of transactions to be performed then that determines the number of fields to be displayed in the sales view. And that works fine. 
The problem is to get each of the transactions to be saved in the database. When I submit and check my database tables, only one transaction is saved.

Comment: This should be showing an error. `get_queryset` should return a queryset, as the badge implies, not a template. You don't need it anyway; remove that method.

Comment: did your try [listview](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview) with walk through `object_list`

Comment: @DanielRoseman It doesn't show any error. But I tried using jut `get` and it gives me an _OSError - Invalid argument-C:\\.path_to_template\\{'all_stock': <QuerySet [<Stock: Stock-design>, <Stock: Stock-design>, <Stock: Stock-design>]>}" _ for 3 items I've saved in the models.

Comment: If you want to display data, you need `ListView` or `DetailView`, depending if you want to display many instances or a single instance. If you want to create data, then you use `CreateView`. You have to reconsider your approach.

Comment: What do you mean, using "just get"? You shouldn't be overriding any methods here at all. Note though that you have the arguments to render the wrong way round.

Comment: @cezar I have tried the ListView. But I still get a blank page.

Comment: @SajiXavier that was a mistake after many trials and not getting it to work. But it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I mean I changed the function definition in the `class BrandsView:'` from `def get_queryset:` to `def get:`, `def display:` , `def get_context_data:` but still doesn't work. I am just getting a blank page. Please I hope you get me.

Comment: why can't you try a simple listview as @DanielRoseman mentioned, class BrandsView(ListView):  model = Stock template_name = 'myapp/brands.html'   and iterate through 'object_list'. if you override get_queryset() it should return a queryset not render output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear that you're trying to run before you can walk here.

Firstly, you should concentrate on getting a simple list view to work, without getting confused about the additional complexity involved in displaying a list in a form view. So, make your view inherit from ListView, and remove *all* the methods. Then fix your template, so that it iterates over `stock_list` or `object_list` rather than just `stock`.

Secondly, once you've got that working, you could try to integrate it with a form. When you do that, learn what methods to override. `get_queryset` *must* return a queryset, it should not render a template. In any case, you should almost never need to render a template manually in a class-based view, because the existing logic will do that for you. And if you want to add a queryset to the template context in a create view, for example, you should be overriding `get_context_data`; which needs to return a dictionary.

Thirdly, if at some point you *do* need to render a template manually, read the documentation to learn the order of parameters to `render`: it is `request, template_name, context`, not as you have it.

Comment: Thanks. It's been very helpful. I have used the generic ListView and it is working except for images. I don't know if it's because of the ListView, But  `{{ name.brand_sample.url }}` is not producing the image.